# Do we need photos for UK Tier 2 Dependent Visa for a 2 month old baby?

Tags: uk-visa

While I am in the UK on Tier-2 General Visa I gave birth to a baby. As I am planning to travel to India, I need to apply a Visa for my baby.

I have filled in the application form. The only documents that were listed for submission were:
1. Birth certificate
2. Bank statements

I was wondering if I need to submit photos of my baby. If yes, how will I take photos of a 2 month old baby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After filling the application form you get two options to submit your documents/biometrics - old method of sending you documents by post and new method where you scan and upload your documents and visit Sopra Steria office for your biometrics.

I had chosen the new method. At Sopra Steria they clicked a picture of my baby and did not require any photos I had taken.

I am not sure about the old method if it still requires photos as I chose the new method.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you need to submit a photo of your baby—this is the case for all UK passport and visa applications, regardless of the age of the child. [You can read the guidance for photos here](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/passport-photographs). The requirements are the same as for adults but with these concessions:

> Children aged five and under do not need to have a neutral expression or to look directly at the camera. Babies under one don’t need to have their eyes open. If the baby’s head needs to be supported, the supporting hand must not be seen. All other photograph standards must be met.

The easiest way to do this is to go to a professional photographer.

Comment: See my answer why I had to undo accept of your answer.